# Using php.ini-production and php.ini-development -> php.ini breaks Kubernetes env vars

Tags: php, docker, kubernetes, environment-variables

I was reading the documentation on Docker hub and came across the:

> Configuration
>   This image ships with the default `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production` configuration files.
>   It is strongly recommended to use the production config for images used in production environments!
>   I followed the steps to use them by adding the following in my `Dockerfile.dev`:

```
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
```

Or

```
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
```

Now when I start my cluster, all of the environmental variables it uses in the `index.php` say `Undefined Index` and the program no longer works. 
The fix is to comment out `RUN mv...` and then everything works again.

Why would it be breaking the Kubernetes environmental variables and how can I get them to work in conjunction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like switch from fetching environmental variables with `$_ENV['<varname>']` to `getenv('<varname>')` fixed the issue.